# Просмотр двоичного кода файла в c++

Tags: c++

Записать содержимое входного файла как `последовательность бит` в другой файл.

То есть, `биты конвертировать в байты`, и записывать в выходной файл

Comment: А как вы себе представляете двоичный код? И как вы его себе представляете в файле? А в текстовом?

Comment: Уточните, добавленные данные двоичного файла должны остаться "как есть" или их представление меняется по каким-то правилам?

Comment: Хм, все файлы, по сути, хранятся в памяти в виде последовательности нулей и единиц. Нужно просмотреть эту последовательность в конкретном файле, а результат вывести в текстовой документ. Реализуется с помощью подключения fstream и ios::binary, только как?

Comment: @logner И в чем проблема? В чтении байтов, в переводе в строковое представление с основанием 2 или в выводе в файл?

Comment: Вы хотите в наглую вывести содержимое файла - побитово?

Comment: @Egor Randomize, именно так

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос более развернуто, что значит "биты конвертировать в байты". Вы в принципе можете открывать файлы либо как последовательность байт, либо как текст.

Answer (score 0):

Программа открывает файл `1.txt`, читает его, и записывает "биты байтами" в `2.txt`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // подключаем файлы
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f("1.txt", ios::binary);
    ofstream o("2.txt", ios::binary);
    char ch;
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "Error opening file!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    while (f.get(ch))
    {
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            o.write((((int)ch & (int)pow(2, i)) > 0 ? "1" : "0"),1);
        }
    }
    f.close();
    o.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Открывает файл любого формата, считывает бинарный код и выводит в текстовой документ *binaryFileCode.txt* .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iterator>

using namespace std; 

 int main () 
{  
            //читаем файл как бинарный   
    ifstream fin("<имя файла или полный адрес файла>", ios::binary); 
            //на случай ошибки чтения
    if (!fin)        
            //вывод ошибки
        cout << "Ошибка! Невозможно прочесть файл." << endl; 
            //если файл прочитан, то
    else     
      {         
            //записываем в переменную прочитанный файл
        string str((istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)), istreambuf_iterator<char>()); 
            //создаём объект для вывода в файл
        ofstream binaryFileCode ;
            //создаём файл, куда будем выводить данные
        binaryFileCode .open("binaryFileCode.txt");
            //записываем в файл данные
        binaryFileCode << str;
            //закрываем файл
        binaryFileCode .close();    
            //выводим сообщение
        cout << "Успешно!";
       }     

 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //для одного символа
using namespace std;
const char c = 'f';
bitset<8> b(c);
cout << b;
// для строки
const string s;
vector< bitset<8> > v;
copy(s.begin(), s.end(), back_inserter(v));
```

допустим  содержимое файла это строка s или вектор строк, тогда вопрос решен